# Deploy Azure FunctionApp container to App Service as linuxFxVersion

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am working on deploy isolated Azure Function App container on Azure App Service.

I have created App Service Plan:

```
"sku": {
    "name": "P1v2",
    "tier": "PremiumV2",
    "size": "P1v2",
    "family": "Pv2",
    "capacity": 1
},
"kind": "linux",
```

with App Service:

```
"kind": "functionapp,linux,container"
```

I am using AzureWebAppContainer@1 task:

```yaml
- task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
  displayName: Deploy to app service
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    appName: my-web-app0name
    imageName:  myacr01.azurecr.io/myregistryname:tag01
    configurationSettings: -linuxFxVersion DOCKER|myacr01.azurecr.io/myregistryname:tag01"
    appSettings: ${{ parameters.appSettings }}
    resourceGroupName: my-resource-group
```

When the task is executed by Azure DevOps yaml pipeline in the logs there is info that:

```
Trying to update App Service Configuration settings. Data: {"appCommandLine":null,"windowsFxVersion":"DOCKER|myacr01.azurecr.io/myregistryname:tag01"}
```

I do not understand why the **windowsFxVersion** is used instead of **linuxFxVersion**.
On resource level in Azure Portal I can also see that I have windowsFxVersion set instead of linuxFxVersion.

Worth to mention that when you are clicking thought the wizard on Azure Portal with default Function App it is set as linuxFxVersion.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14805 I'm scouring the internets for answers along this vein as well. No answers for you just yet, only possible workarounds that in my case seem to break other things...

Answer (score 3):

This is not a valid value:
`-linuxFxVersion DOCKER|myacr01.azurecr.io/myregistryname:tag01"`

Please find available values by [executing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-list-runtimes):

```bash
az webapp list-runtimes --os linux
```

Result:

```json
[
  "DOTNETCORE:7.0",
  "DOTNETCORE:6.0",
  "DOTNETCORE:3.1",
  "NODE:16-lts",
  "NODE:14-lts",
  "PYTHON:3.9",
  "PYTHON:3.8",
  "PYTHON:3.7",
  "PHP:8.0",
  "PHP:7.4",
  "RUBY:2.7",
  "JAVA:17-java17",
  "JAVA:11-java11",
  "JAVA:8-jre8",
  "JBOSSEAP:7-java11",
  "JBOSSEAP:7-java8",
  "TOMCAT:10.0-java17",
  "TOMCAT:10.0-java11",
  "TOMCAT:10.0-jre8",
  "TOMCAT:9.0-java17",
  "TOMCAT:9.0-java11",
  "TOMCAT:9.0-jre8",
  "TOMCAT:8.5-java11",
  "TOMCAT:8.5-jre8"
]
```

I'm using in my current project:

linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNET|6.0'
netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
kind: 'functionapp,linux'

Bicep for creating the app:

```
resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-10-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'linux'
  sku: {
    name: hostingPlanNameSkuName
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource myApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: myAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNET|6.0'
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: [
          '*'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deploying container?
Those settings are in ARM or in AzureWebAppContainer@1 task?

Comment: I'm deploying the function in a container as Container App. My settings are part of the bicep configuration

Comment: I added my bicep to the answer

Comment: can you please also share AzureWebAppContainer@1 task?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the parameter 'kind' must be 'functionapp,linux,container'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I the issue was discussed here:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14805

We ended up using an Azure CLI task instead of AzureWebAppContainer@1:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Update docker image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az webapp config container set --slot staging \
        --name "${{ parameters.webAppName }}" \
        --resource-group "${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}" \
        --docker-registry-server-url "https://***.azurecr.io" \
        --docker-registry-server-user "***" \
        --docker-registry-server-password "$(ACR_PASSWORD)" \
        --docker-custom-image-name "${{ parameters.dockerImage }}"
```

Since our container registry is in a different subscription, so the ACR_PASSWORD is set earlier in the pipeline as an environment variable:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Restore Bicep Modules
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '***' # Service connection to the subscription with container registry
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ACR_PASSWORD;issecret=true]$(az acr credential show -n *** --query passwords[0].value)"
```